# How to calculate radiation pressure?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, pressure, temperature

The radiation energy flow from a heated body is given by:
 $W = σT^4$

$W$ is power by area: $(dE/dt) / A$

For EM waves $E = cP$, where $P$ is momentum.

So $W = σT^4$  =  $c(dP/dt)/A = c(F/A) = cp$, where $p$ is pressure.

Knowing the temperature, can I calculate the radiation pressure for a given radius inside a spherical symmetrical body as:

$p(r) = σ[T(r)]^4 / c?$

Comment: Why would the pressure be dependent on the radius? Are we talking about a spherical cavity filled with black-body radiation?

Comment: No. I think of a situation like Earth, where there is a temperature gradient. The radiation emitted at a shell of radius r being absorbed by the atoms nearby, The change in the EM momentum resulting in a force.